# Update UI from controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a main controller (mainCtrl) with a function that is fired on a click-event, which updates a variable on a "shared" service. ControllerB has a watch on that variable which is in the shared service, and should update the UI when the variable on the shared service changes. However; the UI isn't being updated.

```
//This is the click event on the main controller
this['myClickEvent'] = function()
{
     //The shared variable gets updated here. It's on a service
     shared.resetValue();
}

//This is ControllerB
$scope.$watch(function(){return shared.status},function(status){

//I put an alert here just to verify the watch was being hit everytime the 
//value in the shared service was updated by the main controller 
//it works as expected, the alert is hit everytime.

alert(status.reset)

//However my input value isn't being updated in the view.

this['newValue'] = "New Value"
},true);

//This is my input in the view, not being updated.
<input type="text" ng-disabled="true"  ng-model="xx.newValue">
```

Comment: Not enough context shown. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I figured out the problem. I have a directive that is returning the "controllerAs" attribute (controllerAs: 'xx'). In my ControllerB when I was updating the model using the "this"  keyword (this["newValue"]), it wouldn't update the UI. However; when I removed the "this" keyword and started using the "$scope" keyword ($scope['newValue']) my UI was being updated as expected. Not sure why I had to use "$scope" and not "this" to update the view/UI. I was told that if I set the controllerAs attribute on my directive, I could use the "this" keyword in my controller instead of $scope